# How to run JS scripts every 5 seconds with pm2

Tags: javascript, process, cron, pm2

I installed pm2 in my server. I created `ecosystem.config.js` with following code:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
  {
    name   : "deploy",
    script : "deploy.js",
    watch       : true,
    restart_delay: 5000,
    instances: 1,
    cwd: '/usr/share/sails/scripts/',
    log_date_format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z',
    out_file: '/usr/share/sails/scripts/deploy.log',
    error_file: '/usr/share/sails/scripts/deploy.log',
    exec_mode: 'fork',
    env: {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
    },
    env_production : {
       "NODE_ENV": "production"
    }
  },
  {
    name   : "check-status",
    script : "checkStatus.js",
    watch       : true,
    restart_delay: 5000,
    instances: 1,
    cwd: '/usr/share/sails/scripts/',
    log_date_format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z',
    out_file: '/usr/share/sails/scripts/checkStatus.log',
    error_file: '/usr/share/sails/scripts/checkStatus.log',
    exec_mode: 'fork',
    env: {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
    },
    env_production : {
       "NODE_ENV": "production"
    }
  },
  {
    name   : "get-contract",
    script : "getContractByHash.js",
    watch       : true,
    restart_delay: 5000,
    instances: 1,
    cwd: '/usr/share/sails/scripts/',
    log_date_format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z',
    out_file: '/usr/share/sails/scripts/getContractByHash.log',
    error_file: '/usr/share/sails/scripts/getContractByHash.log',
    exec_mode: 'fork',
    env: {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
    },
    env_production : {
       "NODE_ENV": "production"
    },
  }

]
}
```

I have set `restart_delay: 5000`.
Then I run script `ecosystem.config.js` via command `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` and all scripts run more faster then I set.
They run 2-4 times per second.

1. What am I need to set property for run scripts every 5 sceonds?
2. How can I run `ecosystem.config.js` after 20 seconds after command call: 
   `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`? What parameters should I set?

Answer (score 0):

You better to use single continuous process with infinite loop using intervals inside.

```
setInterval(doStuff, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nice [sails-hook-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-cron) for sails, which is basically a crontab editor.